# What is the flying speed when spectating a match/watching a replay in Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

I'd like to know the speed that a spectator can fly at. Would be cool to measure some long distances in the game like the height of the Lijiang tower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I calculated these values based on a replay recording by walking a distance with Reinhardt holding shield (this has a speed of 3.85m/s) and measuring the time (straight line of 60m on Anubis). Then I flew the same distance in the replay viewer and measured the time which resulted in:

Flying speed (slow) = 5.22m/s (slightly slower than default walking speed)

Flying speed (fast) = 26m/s

I used this method to measure the height of Lijiang tower: It's 1038m tall.